# Is there a Hidden subgroup problem in BQP but suspected not to be in NP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing, np

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_subgroup_problem) lists HSP problems in abelian and non-abelian groups. So does the following (extensive) [compedium](https://quantumalgorithmzoo.org/).

I searched and found none is a BQP-complete (or even BQP-hard) problem.

There has been a discussion on this site about whether **HSP on an abelian group** can be BQP complete; [Link](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1298/68722). The answer is suspected to be negative (due to a known oracle separation; see link).

A version of the shortest vector problem is known to be NP-hard (due to Ajtai, 1998). SVP is an HSP in the non-abelian group.

My query:

> Is there a hidden subgroup problem in BQP (or even BQP-Hard) that is suspected not to be in NP?

> Is there some reason for not finding any HSP in $BQP\backslash NP$?

Note:

- I am assuming conjecture $BQP \nsubseteq NP$ and $NP \nsubseteq BQP$ holds true.
- I am looking for (full) HSP (both abelian and non-abelian cases).
- Assume this is in the context of (corresponding) decision version for HSP problems.

Comment: When you write $BQP/NP$, do you mean $BQP\setminus NP$? When you write $BQP\ne NP$, do you mean $BQP\nsubseteq NP$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, one typo removed. One clarification added.